# Looking for Book or Short Story: A girl tries to contact aliens in a bathroom

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, books

It's been years since I read this story, I don't remember where I read it but it was about a girl who was trying to contact aliens. I remember she dyed her hair blonde because she thought it would make the contact process easier? I remember that she was bullied in school, too. The main thing that sticks in my mind is a scene where she was in a bathroom, crinkling something, trying to contact the aliens. Maybe mental illness was also a theme?
If anyone has any idea what I'm talking about, I'd love to hear from you! It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Did she succeed in contacting aliens? Are there any aliens in the story? Is it a science fiction story, or is it just a story about a delusional girl who thinks she can contact aliens?

Comment: I wish I could remember but above is all I've got D=

Comment: @Hay How many years has it been since your read the story?

Comment: I think I read it in elementary or middle school and I'm 22 now so 10 years ago or more